# Laravel 5.2 eloquent query with local scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent, local, scopes

I wanted to know if its possible to use Laravel's local scope between two or more Models using join or sub query?

For example this is User model with scope active.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
      return $query->where('active', 1);
    }
}
```

Other Model is UserSubscription with scope.

```
class UserSubscription extends Model
{
    public function scopeType($query, $type)
    {
      return $query->where('type', $type);
    }
}
```

How to make use of both scopes in single query? Following statement will not work.

```
$users = Users::active()
        ->join('UserSubscription', 'users.id', '=','UserSubscription.user_id')
        ->UserSubscription::type()
        ->get();
```

I am using Laravel 5.2. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes

Answer (score 0):

If you made right your model relationships in both model classes you can make a query like this:

```
$users= User::where('active', 1)->whereHas('user_subscriptions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', $type);
})->get();
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use Laravel model relationship because of performance issues. Moreover, I want to make use of local scopes. i.e.         $users = Users::active()->join('user_subscriptions', 'users.id', '=','user_subscriptions.user_id')
        ->UserSubscription::type()
        ->get(); @lewis4u

Comment: But as far as I know the scopes are based on eloquent. And I would like to know if you could post a link or something of an example with eloquent performance issues.